# PHP: print text without having to go to the top of the page

Tags: php, ajax, dom, request

I have a function that sends mails. Here it is. As you can see at the end if all checks are corrects it echoes an "Email sent!" and there are errors if user doesn't compile some inputs.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    ... BLAHBLAH
    // Validation
    if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Field is mandatory. ";
    }
    if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Email format is wrong!";
    }


    if(empty($errors))
    {
        // send the email
        $to = $your_email;
        $subject="My subject";
        ... BLAH BLAH

        $headers = "From: $from \r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers);

        echo 'Email sent';
    }
}
```

Email sending works fine. The problem is that this form is inside a jQuery toggled div. And when a message needs to be displayed (wheter is an error message that a field is mandatory or that email has been sent), the user gets redirected to the top of the page and the toggled div (the one in which the form is in) goes back to visibility:hidden.
How can I print the messages without having the user go to the top of the page?

It seems I need to use `jQuery.ajax()` but I don't know how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to see your jQuery code. However, that being said, if you are submitting the form to the same page that displays it and the submission is not handled asynchronously, the page is likely reloading, which will cause it to appear to "jump" to the top. I would write an Ajax method to handle the form submission via POST. You can use event.preventDefault(); to prevent the page from "jumping" when the form is submitted.

**Update based on OP's reply:**

1. Temporarily remove the code the shows and hides the contact form.
2. Implement the jQuery validation plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation as the form handler:
    
   A. Bind the call to this plugin to the click event on the submit button.
    
   B. Use event.preventDefault(); to stop the form from submitting.
   C. On success, the validation plugin will call an Ajax method to post your form.
3. Write an Ajax method to post your form. This method should have two callbacks:
   .done() -- executes if the form posts successfully
   .fail() -- executes if there is an error.
    In your done method you can hide the form. Your fail method can display an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! jQuery code is easy: http://pastebin.com/zEQKHaRc

Can you help me rewriting the button `<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">` with an ajax function? I'm not really familiar with JS..

Comment: I just updated my answer based on your response. You will likely need to do some research and practice some jQuery tutorials but this should give you a solid game plan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //ajax code that send to server side here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But, sorry.. I'm not an expert.. what do you mean by 'ajax code that send to server side'?
I have a form with many `input` (and relative `values="<?php echo htmlentities($SOMETHING) ?>`"). Then I have $SOMETHING = $_POST['SOMETHING']; and a function which put them in the email body and call to the PHP email function.